# Type error trying to use join function on list of strings in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I'm working a dataframe that has a column containing lists (containing strings), and I'm trying to apply a lambda function to the column to convert the lists into strings using join().

```
df['colors_unpacked'] = df['colors'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

I've done this before and it's worked in a separate project with no issues but now I'm getting this error message: **TypeError: can only join an iterable**

Is there a better way I can do this? How can I accomplish this without getting an error.

Comment: Are you sure that the column's elements are actually lists, and not a different type?

Comment: I'm quite sure the column's elements are lists. It's letters (indicating colors) with square brackets around them.

Comment: What does `.apply(lambda x: type(x))` spit out?